# Why does "we have been over this" mean something different from "we are over this"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialects, idiom-meaning, perfect-aspect, register

The whole sentence is:

> We’ve been over this a thousand times. The data is irrefutable!

What does it mean to "have been over this" here in this context?  How does this meaning differ here from the more common one seen with "be over this" like in "we are over this" and "we were over this" where it simply means that we're done with it?

Why do the compound versions, "we've been over this" and "we'd been over this", trigger a completely different meaning than we see with the simple versions like "we are over this" and "we were over this"?

Is this a common usage in English-speaking countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Go over' is a multi word verb (MWV); these are usually classed as separate lexemes from the simplex verb, and often have dissimilar meanings. Consider

- *He **looked** up the road.* [simplex verb + prepositional phrase showing where 'he' looked]
- *He **looked up** the information.* [MWV + Direct Object, 'He researched / checked the information.']

......................

> **go over** {phrasal verb} [MWV in some terminologies]
>
> go over something:
>
> ​to examine or check something carefully
>
> - *Go over your work before you hand it in.*
>
> ​to study something carefully, especially by repeating it
>
> - He went over the events of the day in his mind (= thought about them carefully).

[[Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-over#:%7E:text=go%20over-,phrasal%20verb,before%20you%20hand%20it%20in.)]

'We have gone over this' and 'We have been over this' are equivalent.

'We have been over this [already]' is often used to mean 'I thought we'd finished discussing this. We should have!'

...................

'Be over something' and the dynamic 'get over something' are also arguably related MWVs but with a different meaning:

> **get over** (1): to recover from a misfortune or disappointment (death of a loved one, end of a relationship, sickness, etc)
>
> - *It took her almost three months to get over losing her job.*

[[Dynamic English](https://www.dynamicenglish.cl/blog-feed/phrasal-verbs-with-over)]

Comment: I think *we've **been through** this material before* **also** means the same thing as *we've **gone through** this material before* means, just like in this case. But when you're through the material, you're done with it. There’s some curious transformation between *be* and *go*  (and sometimes *get* or even *come*) that seems to turn up only in the compound forms. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is quite a common phrase. In this context 'been over' means 'addressed' or 'discussed'. So you could instead say, "We've addressed/discussed this a thousand times."

Comment: "Gone over" is also used with this meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to sum up with an *over*all improv lol (hope it's accurate)

They are revisiting the subject *over and over*, they appear to be quite *over* it (fed-up) with this topic *all over the place*, until it's *over* when they get it *over* with. Then they call it *over* and are finally *over* the issue, so they can enjoy another conversation *over* coffee.